# ¿Que expresión regular usar para dos palabras separadas con un espacio?

Tags: phalcon

Hola tengo una expresión regular que quiero usar para validar que puede o no contener espacios o 2 palabras separadas con espacios

```
{nombre:[a-zA-Z0-9\ \-\w]+}
```

Lo cual no funciona espero me puedan ayudar

Comment: Mostra casos validos e invalidos de lo que queres validar

Comment: pues lo estoy usando para una busqueda con un like por lo tanto puede ser una palabra o 2 o hasta 3 palabras divididas por espacios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la expresión siguiente:

```
^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){2}
```

Demo: [Visualización](https://regex101.com/r/K9Xi3b/1/)

Comment: no se si lo estoy agregando mal. ¿Quedaria asi? `{nombre:^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){2}+}`

Comment: En donde se utiliza la expresión regular (motor de javascript)? Si si seria mejor que la compilaras con new `RegExp('^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){2}')`.